# How to conditionally replace R data.table columns upon merge?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, merge, data.table

I have the following two data.tables

```
library(data.table)

dt1 = data.table(index_column = c(12, 17, 29, 34, 46), column1 = c("dog", "cat", "bird", "elephant", "bird"), column2 = c(482, 391, 567, 182, 121))

dt2 = data.table(index_column = c(17, 29, 46), column1 = c("cat", "penguin", "bird"))

> dt1
   index_column  column1 column2
1:           12      dog     482
2:           17      cat     391
3:           29     bird     567
4:           34 elephant     182
5:           46     bird     121


> dt2
   index_column column1
1:           17     cat
2:           29 penguin
3:           46    bird
```

Upon merging these two data.table solely on the shared `index_column` with

```
merged = merge(dt1, dt2, by="index_column", all=TRUE)
```

the resulting `data.table` is:

```
   index_column column1.x column2 column1.y
1:           12       dog     482        NA
2:           17       cat     391       cat
3:           29      bird     567   penguin
4:           34  elephant     182        NA
5:           46      bird     121      bird
```

I am interested in replacing values of `column1.x` with the values of `column1.y` if they are not `NA`. Most of the values will be the same, but those that are not (e.g. bird/penguin) should be replaced.

One could do this would an if statement, e.g.

```
if ((merged$column1.x != merged$column1.y) & !is.na(merged$column1.y)){
   merged$column1.x = merged$column1.y
}

merged$column1.y = NULL
```

My concern is that this isn't a very `data.table` solution. It will not scale very well if the `data.table` has millions of rows.

How would one conditionally replace values of one column based on another column in an R data.table? Is it more efficient to simply replace one with the other, ignoring the NA's?

Comment: something like `dt[!is.na(column1.y), column1.x := column1.y]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the `on` based approach

```
dt1[dt2, column1 := i.column1, on = .(index_column)]
dt1
#   index_column  column1 column2
#1:           12      dog     482
#2:           17      cat     391
#3:           29  penguin     567
#4:           34 elephant     182
#5:           46     bird     121
```

Comment: There's no need to merge the data.tables then?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang  It is a `join` which I assume gives the expected output without creating additional columns in the input data

Comment: how would you proceed if  you had multiple columns (same length) instead of column1 and also multiple index columns?